# ExtJS, SenchaTouch - LocalStorage updates only work on first page load?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I've built a working example of the breakage [here](http://www.stefankendall.com/files/stackoverflow/broken/test.html). The first time you load the page, the defaults are loaded into the form. When you change the data and refresh, the last-changed-value is present. However, after the first page view (refresh again), no further changes are persisted, as it looks like a value called `my-proxy-undefined` is getting set instead of `my-proxy-1` getting updated. What's going on?

**Model**:

```
Ext.regModel('MyModel', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'var1', type: 'integer'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'my-proxy'
    }
});
```

**Store**:

```
 var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                    model: 'MyModel',
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(store, records, successful) {
                            if (this.getCount() == 0) {
                                console.log("Count 0, loading defaults");
                                this.add(app.defaults.vars);
                                this.sync();
                            }

                            myForm.load(store.first());
                        }
                    },
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoSave: true
                });
```

**Change listeners on the form:**

```
listeners:{
      change:function(el, newValue, oldValue) {
      var maxesRecord = myStore.first();
      maxesRecord.set(el.name, newValue);
      maxesRecord.save();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.regModel('Maxes', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'var1', type: 'integer'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'my-proxy'
    }
});
```

Because of a usability bug, you need to set the id as a field.

Comment: Indeed. I'm hoping this gets changed/fixed in 2.0, but in 2.0PR3, localStorage is broken entirely. :P